# MSCRM 2011 Total record count by day

Tags: reporting-services, count, report, dynamics-crm

One of our team who maintains subscriber content in `CRM` requested a report that displays total number of active records, email subscriber and email unsubscribers. I can create a report that shows current total for all three subject above. But can't show the historical details.

For example: Active used count for yesterday was 400K then today 403K and tomorrow 4007K, I want to produce a graph that shows the climbing of these numbers by day.

My first thought is to create new entity that stores all these details or a new table in sql and use that in reporting with SSRS.

I want to know if you guys have ever come across this and if so what you think is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try once Group by date (Or)

Create a new Entity and write a workflow that runs every day and stores all the counts date wise.
fetch the custom entity data into the report.

Comment: Thank Raju for your reply. I have done just that, except, I am running a package overnight that gets all counts and stores it in to a newly created table on a local sql server. All reports on total counts are now created using data from this new table.